# Mapping one column in a table to multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a new product development creating a WMS system. I have done it in past using ASP, VB, and other techniques where we did not hard code the mapping. But now i am working on it using MVC and entity frame work and i am stumped. How can i map one column in transaction table to a column in multiple tables.

I have transaction table 
trans 
Transid
orderref
TType
productid
qty
....(More Columns) 
now the orderref will hold either Receiptkey, orderkey , movementkey, adjustmentkey and the TType column will tell me which type of transaction i am dealing with and based on that i would know which table to link further. Now how can i achieve this in Entity Frame work. This is the most important step. I have done this many times in my other languages but now using EF i am stuck. Please help. I have checked a lot online but i have not found it. I am new to MVC and entity frame work architecture. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you should use Table-per-Type hierarchy. But your column TType is not necessary for this, cause EF match this through foreign key links.
How to do this in codefirst approach, you can read [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).
In short: you map your base type to base table and map your inherited types to linked tables with details.

Example:
You can create in database three tables:

`TransactionBases` with columns `TransId`, and some other common columns for all transactions;

`ConcreteTransactionAs` with columns `TransId` that is primary key and foreign key to `TransactionBase`, and other specific to this transaction type columns;

`ConcreteTransactionBs` with columns `TransId` that is primary key and foreign key to `TransactionBase`, and other specific to this transaction type columns;

Then in your code you create three entity classes:

```
public class TransactionBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TransId {get;set;}

    ... //other common properties for all transaction types
}

[Table("ConcreteTransactionAs")]
public class ConcreteTransactionA: TransactionBase
{
    ...//specific to this transaction type columns
}

[Table("ConcreteTransactionBs")]
public class ConcreteTransactionB: TransactionBase
{
    ...//specific to this transaction type columns
}
```

Comment: So Kirill basically i have to create an abstract class and inherit it in 2 classes and instantiate those classes. So what will it create in the database? Sorry i might sound quite naive here but i am not so well versed in EF codefirst mapping always did the other way around.

Comment: you can create tables in database and then map to that tables in codefirst approach. Codefirst means that mapping is in code, not in xml file. I will update answer with example.

Comment: Hello Kirill, thanks for the eg Going by this example i will have to add a new class each time a new T Type is introduced. So the transactions will be spread across multiple tbls. This might be keeping in tune with the EF rules but it will add extra complexity if i have to create another system or sub system based upon the base tables using some other prog language. currently I have 5 T Type so i will have one trans hdr tbl and 5 detail tbls each mapped to one T Type.Every instance of the detail is created i will have a new entry being created in the header as well. My assumption is correct?

Comment: If you don't want to use new transaction tables in ef project, you should not add new inherited class. And yes, if you add new concrete transaction to set of its type, in db record will be added to both tables (base and detail)

Comment: thanks Kirill you have been very helpful. To be honest i dont think many new transaction types will crop up, but if i have to extend the functionality of the system i will have to keep it open to addition of new transactions. Just to know what i am getting into how diff it would be to add new transactions in this model? I mean technical difficulties i will have to face in terms of adding new logical links and all.

Comment: You should add new detail table to DB and add new inherited from TransactionBase class with attribute [Table(nameofnewdetailtable)] Its all.